# Xamarin.UITest iOS ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD directive is confusing

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest, xamarin-test-cloud

The documentation found [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/preparing-for-upload/uitest) is confusing.

Regarding configuring test cloud for iOS they say the following:

[image]

### So here are my questions:

- Can I leave the `#if ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD` directive in both my release and dev builds?
- If I leave the `#if ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD` directive in my release build, can I submit this to Apple play store and they won't reject it?
- It sounds like the `#if ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD` directive automatically works in debug build, correct, I don't have to configure anything else...?
- If the above is correct, should I only submit Debug builds to the test cloud?  Shouldn't I be testing release builds, not debug?  I thought during testing you wanted to test as close as possible to exactly what the user will be running.

Answer (score 1):

As I continued doing research I found the answer [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/get-started-xamarin-forms#ios-application-project)

Here is the section for reference:

[image]

Comment: Good digging. We've had a few discussions internally about changing the ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD symbol to be simply DEBUG instead but feel that the addition of a new symbol (whilst initially confusing) does give more flexibility and makes it easier to support multiple build configurations.

Comment: @OwenNiblock It would be better if it was DEBUG because the vast majority of inexperienced people come across this when publishing tot he App Store is imminent and why include an advanced topic during such a crucial release-to-store period. I'd have saved half a day if the Microsoft documentation was as thorough as Helzgate's above.